# Adding data to an existing excel file using jxl

Tags: java, jxl, saving-data

So I have a program that runs a timer in the background counting the time I use certain applications.
My goal is now to save the total time to an excel file (at the end of each day or the next day). I have already created a template with months as columns and the rows as dates (1-31).
So my question is: 
Is there a way to write a single cell to an existing sheet without first copying the existing file and creating a new one?